# Not able to find element in pop up in appium

Tags: android, xpath, appium

[image: screenshot]

In my app profile I want to select Religion, so when I am clicking on Religion one pop up is opening and I have to choose one element from there,
Only "Index" and "text" values are different for each element, "Id" same for all element.

1. But while taking "xpath" using "text" and "index" values, not getting the element.
2. I am using scroll to method also but not getting the element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody help me it's urgent for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you share an appium screenshot to make things clear over this && also the code you have tried

Comment: Please find the screen shot attached

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vxkOu.png

Comment: and your code that you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

get all the index and its corresponding religions and click by index number

```
List<WebElement> ls = driver.findElementsById("android:id/numberpicker_input");             
System.out.println("no of religions" + ls.size());              
ls.get(0).click
```

Comment: Hi ,Thanks 4 reply. here there is no click available, only I have to scroll elements and click  on "OK" button.

Comment: List<WebElement> ls = obj.findElementsById("android:id/numberpicker_input");

              System.out.println("no of religions" + ls.size());


                      ls.get(2);

Comment: can i use any other methods for this?

Comment: whats the o/p of  the print of ls.size

Comment: using this code://Select Religion
          
        List<WebElement> ls = obj.findElementsById("android:id/numberpicker_input");

              System.out.println("no of religions" + ls.size());


                      ls.get(0);   o/p is:no of religions1

Comment: it only selecting Religion: Agnostic, I am not able to select Other religion

Comment: whats the op pf thisstatement System.out.println("no of religions" + ls.size());

Comment: o/p is:no of religions1

Answer (score 0):

You can click by using click method:

```
driver.findElementByName("your religion name").click();
```

and scroll by using this method:

```
public void keepScrollingUntilElementFound(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (isElementPresent("name=" + name)) {
                break;
            } else {
                scrollDown();
                scrollDown();
            }
        }
    }



 public void scrollDown() {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int x = size.width / 2;
        int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.60);
        int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.10);
        driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy, 2000);
    }



 public boolean isElementPresent(String name) {
        try {
            driver.findElementByName(name);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```